# Symfony while does not work

Tags: php, symfony, while-loop

Trying to do a dropdown list with this query and trying to return an array with the while to do that and the while don't work :s

```
static public function getConta() {
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addSelectColumn(MEMataPeer::CONTA);
    $criteria->addGroupByColumn(MEMataPeer::CONTA);
    $contas = array();
    $stmt = MEMatalPeer::doSelectStmt($criteria);        
    echo "##".$stmt->rowCount();
    while($res = $stmt->fetchColumn(0)) { // <- this while don't work don't    know why ?????
        $contas[$res] = $res;
        echo "<br/>[$res]";`
```

Comment: Define "don't work". I've neatened up your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
$stmt->fetchColumn(0)
```

has a false evaluation (probably a null result).  In this case there is nothing to while over.

Comment: don 't know why but i do a variavel print_r(stmt->fetchColumn(0) before the while and it's done .. after i have done $test = stmt->fetchColumn(0) and its running good :o